# expected 'double *' but argument is of type 'double' and incompatible type for argument 2/3/4/5 of function

Tags: c++, c, c89, numerical-analysis

I'm begging for your help guys, I'm not the best coder, and I've spent so much time on this, I'm so tired and depressed :[

Basically I want to pass an `int`, and 4 single dimension arrays to a function that shall return a pointer to an array(solution vector for my purpose) which I understood in C I could define in a function through the order static.

Basically it says that it doesn't understand why a double type array is passed to a function that returns a pointer to double, and for some reason it expects a pointer to be the argument as well as I understood it.
and I think it dragged to the bolded line, because there's a problem of compatibility, at least I think thats the reason for that error. 
Please help me guys :]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4

double* thomas_algorithm(int n, double c[], double b[], double a[], double 
d[]);

int main()
{

int i, n;
double* p;
double a[N-1]={0}, b[N]={0}, c[N-1]={0}, d[N]={0};

printf("please enter the order of the coefficient matrix:\n");

scanf("%d", &n);

printf("please insert the vector c:\n");

for(i=0; i<N-1; i++)
{
    scanf("%lf", &c[i]);
}

printf("please insert the vector b:\n");

for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    scanf("%lf", &b[i]);
}

printf("please insert the vector a:\n");

for(i=0; i<N-1; i++)
{
    scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
}

printf("please insert the vector d:\n");

for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    scanf("%lf", &d[i]);
}

**p=thomas_algorithm(n, c[N-1], b[N], a[N-1], d[N]);**

for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    printf("x(%d)=%f", i+1, p+i);
}

return 0;
}

double* thomas_algorithm(int n, double c[], double b[], double a[], double 
d[]) {

int i;
static double x[N]={0};

for(i=1; i<n-1; i++) /*factorization phase*/
{
    b[i]=b[i]-(a[i]/b[i-1])*c[i-1];
    d[i]=d[i]-(a[i]/b[i-1])*d[i-1];

}
/*backward substitution*/

x[N-1]=d[N-1]/b[N-1];

for(i=n-2; i>-1; i++)
{
    x[i]=(d[i]-c[i]*x[i+1])/b[i];
}
    return x;
}
```

Comment: `p=thomas_algorithm(n, c[N-1], b[N], a[N-1], d[N]);` -> `p=thomas_algorithm(n, c, b, a, d);`. `a[i]` is a specific element, while `a` is the array itself (which decays to a pointer).

Comment: @Osiris Exactly ! Write an answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function call is wrong.

if you have an array `int a[N];` and a function `void func(int a[])` you need to call the function like `func(a);`.

In your call you pass the Nth element of the array `a[N]`, therefore the compile error since it is of type `double` and not `double *`. (It is also an out of bounds access)

The correct function call would be:

```
p=thomas_algorithm(n, c, b, a, d);
```